# ESRI Javascript API Export to Shapefile and CSV

Tags: shapefile, javascript, web-mapping, export, php

I am working on a Javascript Web Application using the ESRI Javascript API v3.3.  My application allows the user to edit and query data and also provides a table for attributes.

I would like the user to be able to export map data to a Shapefile or export the table data to a CSV.

Is this possible with Javascript along?  If not, my web application is running on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk service with PHP.  I've never written anything in PHP, but can this be done with PHP?  How would I go about doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you want to create a shapefile for download, you should be able to publish an async geoprocess that will return a link to the location of the generated shapefile on your ArcGIS Server. You call this service from the javascript API using esri.tasks.Geoprocessor. Take a look at the clip-and-ship example. It uses a file gdb, but you should be able to change it to a shapefile if you need.

javascript side:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/gp_clipasync.html

server side:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Clip_and_ship/01540000035r000000/

2) In javascript, I've successfully used the jquery based DataTables library to create a very functional data grid http://www.datatables.net/. DataTables has a plugin called TableTools that can save table data as a CSV file among other things -- it includes a tiny flash plugin for the local file saving. It has worked well for me. You could potentially put json geometry into a column. See this post for a sample [Spatial query in ArcGIS Javascript Api 3.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54442/spatial-query-in-arcgis-javascript-api-3-1/54489#54489)

3) I'm sure you could do it with php accessing a shapefile library, write it out, zip it up and send back a link, but I don't have a recipe for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We aren't actually using ArcGIS server for our app.  Instead, we are using ArcGIS Online to host the feature services.  Do you know if AGOL allows geoprocessing like in the Clip and Ship example you provided?

Comment: I am using a `dojo` `dgrid` for my table.  Do you think it is possible to mix and match the `dgrid` table with the `TableTools`?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_ArcGIS_Online_hosted_services/01w100000038000000/

Comment: Yes, you should be able to mix and match. Of course, there is the slight issue that it makes the initial download a touch larger, but it's not that big a deal.

Comment: The link to the JavaScript example is currently dead -- do you know a different link?